# dos selectOneMenu anidados dan error Cannot convert of type class java.lang.Integer to class

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estoy intentado que hacer dos selectOneMenu anidados, uno contiene las provincias y el segundo las ciudades de esas provincias.
Me salta un error, al seleccionar la provincia, y no logro descubrir que es lo que hice mal.

El error:

```
SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-22) javax.faces.component.UpdateModelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
```

> Cannot convert 2 of type class java.lang.Integer to class
>   ar.com.kompass.model.Provincia

```
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:866)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processUpdates(UIInput.java:749)
at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:577)
at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
```

Si mal no entiendo, el mensaje "Cannot convert 2 of...." se refiere al valor
seleccionado, en este caso el valor 2 de provincias, y que no logra "convertirlo" a un objeto provincia. ¿como soluciono esto?

**El fragmento de código de la vista que genera el error:**

```
    <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Provincia " />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="cboProvincia"
                            value="#{cuentaBean.cuenta.provincia}" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Debe seleccionar una provincia"
                            converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Seleccione--" itemValue="#{null}"
                                noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{cuentaBean.lstProvincias}" var="prov"
                                itemLabel="#{prov.nombre}" itemValue="#{prov.id}" />
                            <f:ajax event="change"
                                listener="#{cuentaBean.listarLocalidades()}"
                                execute="cboProvincia" render="cboLocalidad" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Localidad " />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="cboLocalidad"
                            value="#{cuentaBean.cuenta.localidad}" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="Debe seleccionar una Localidad"
                            converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Seleccione--" itemValue="#{null}"
                                noSelectionOption="true" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{cuentaBean.lstLocalidades}" var="loca"
                                itemLabel="#{loca.nombre}" itemValue="#{loca}" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
```

**Este es el Bean:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped public class CuentaBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ICuentaService cuentaService;

@Inject
private Cuenta cuenta;
@Inject
private IProvinciaService provinciaService;
@Inject
private ILocalidadService localidadService;


private List<Cuenta> lstCuentas;
private List<Provincia> lstProvincias;
private List<Localidad> lstLocalidades;
private int codigoProvincia;

public int getCodigoProvincia() {
    return codigoProvincia;
}

public void setCodigoProvincia(int codigoProvincia) {
    this.codigoProvincia = codigoProvincia;
}

public Cuenta getCuenta() {
    return cuenta;
}

public void setCuenta(Cuenta cuenta) {
    this.cuenta = cuenta;
}


@PostConstruct
public void init(){     
    lstCuentas = new ArrayList<>();
    lstProvincias = new ArrayList<>();
    lstLocalidades = new ArrayList<>();
    this.listarProvincias();
}


public List<Cuenta> getLstCuentas() {
    return lstCuentas;
}

public void setLstCuentas(List<Cuenta> lstCuentas) {
    this.lstCuentas = lstCuentas;
}


public List<Provincia> getLstProvincias() {
    return lstProvincias;
}


public void setLstProvincias(List<Provincia> lstProvincias) {
    this.lstProvincias = lstProvincias;
}

public List<Localidad> getLstLocalidades() {
    return lstLocalidades;
}


public void setLstLocalidades(List<Localidad> lstLocalidades) {
    this.lstLocalidades = lstLocalidades;
}

public void listarProvincias() {
    try {
        //lstCuentas = cuentaService.listar();
        lstProvincias= provinciaService.listar();
        //lstLocalidades= localidadService.listar(idProv);      
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void listarLocalidades() {
    try {
        System.out.print(this.codigoProvincia);
        lstLocalidades= localidadService.listar(this.codigoProvincia);          
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}


}
```

Y por ultimo el **Modelo cuentas**, que tal vez podria ser el motivo del error:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "cuenta") public class Cuenta  implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "nombre", length = 30, nullable = false)
private String nombre;
@Column(name = "domicilio", length = 30, nullable = false)
private String domicilio;
private short altura;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idprov" , nullable = false)
private Provincia provincia;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="idloca" , nullable = false)
private Localidad localidad;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public String getDomicilio() {
    return domicilio;
}
public void setDomicilio(String domicilio) {
    this.domicilio = domicilio;
}
public short getAltura() {
    return altura;
}
public void setAltura(short altura) {
    this.altura = altura;
}


public Localidad getLocalidad() {
    return localidad;
}
public void setLocalidad(Localidad localidad) {
    this.localidad = localidad;
}

public Provincia getProvincia() {
    return provincia;
}
public void setProvincia(Provincia provincia) {
    this.provincia = provincia;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Cuenta other = (Cuenta) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en la incoherencia entre los tipos del `value` del `selectOneMenu` y de los `itemValue` de los `selectItems`

El `value` del `selectOneMenu` debería poder ser mapeado a uno de los `itemValue` de los posibles items, sin embargo, en tu código (*quito partes que no estan relacionadas al problema*):

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="cboProvincia"
     value="#{cuentaBean.cuenta.provincia}"
     converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
     <f:selectItems value="#{cuentaBean.lstProvincias}" var="prov"
     itemLabel="#{prov.nombre}" itemValue="#{prov.id}" />

 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

- el `value` del `selectOneMenu` es un objeto del tipo `Provincia`
- los `itemValue` de los `selectItems`es `prov.id`, es decir, un `Integer`.

Por lo que el converter (`omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter`), al actualizar el modelo con el valor seleccionado, trata de convertir de `Integer` a `Provincia` y se produce la excepción:

> Cannot convert 2 of type class java.lang.Integer to class
>   ar.com.kompass.model.Provincia

Lo correcto sería alguna de estas dos opciones, dependiendo de tu diseño:

1. Que el `value` del `selectOneMenu` sea `#{cuentaBean.cuenta.provincia.id}` y mantener los `selectItems` tal cual están

> ```
>   <p:selectOneMenu id="cboProvincia"
>                  value="#{cuentaBean.cuenta.provincia.id}"
>                  converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
>                  <f:selectItems value="#{cuentaBean.lstProvincias}" var="prov"
>                  itemLabel="#{prov.nombre}" itemValue="#{prov.id}" />
>     </p:selectOneMenu>
> ```

2. Que el `itemValue` de los selectItems sea `#{prov}`y mantener el `value` del `selectOneMenu` tal cual está definido.

> ```
>  <p:selectOneMenu id="cboProvincia"
>          value="#{cuentaBean.cuenta.provincia}"
>          converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
>          <f:selectItems value="#{cuentaBean.lstProvincias}" var="prov"
>          itemLabel="#{prov.nombre}" itemValue="#{prov}" />
>      </p:selectOneMenu>
> ```